# How can I make the back button goes to the previous step

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a quiz app from a json file.
How can i make the back button go to the previous step. So I want to make the back button returns to what was previously selected.

```
 const navigateBack = () => {
    let index = 1;
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/steps')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        const current = res.data.filter((element: any) => destinationstepId !== element.id)

      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question ids are sequential define an index as a state using state hook, else you can define history as an array state and move through the array when you are going backward and forward.